# Better Indy for Dephi 2007

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Which better is using default indy10 that's comes with Delphi 2007 or upgrade it to latest snapshot version and why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Always keep up with the latest version. It contains bug fixes. If you report a problem with the stock version supplied with Delphi, the first advice you'll get is to upgrade to the latest version because your bug has probably already been fixed.

Comment: Agreed.  Especially considering that D2007 was released several years ago, and there has been a LOT of work on Indy since then, especially when dealing with Unicode, but also in other areas related to Indy's various protocols support.

Answer (score 3):

Do not always keep up with the latest version. Download latest version now and start your project with it. Then do not keep up until you have a good reason or enough time to recheck all the functionality. Otherwise, you depend on vendor and trust him that he will never break existing code in his bug fixes or new features introduces. Having that much trust is too much for me. Of course, you should check from time to time for new versions and decide if it's worth upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

> Always keep up with the latest version.

Oh no, it isn't for novices. For exapmle, 21 august 2010 I've downloaded latest snapshot of Indy 10.5.7 and it doesn't works with cookies at all! Yes, I've found an error and patch it, but you must realize that you can lost a great part of functionality using snapshots under active development. So, I'm using Indy for many years and have a lot of patches in my projects folder. Every update is a headache! Sorry, Remy Lebeau, but it's true.

Comment: Have you been posting any of those patches back to the Indy team?  I doubt it, otherwise they would have been incorporated so you don't have to maintain patches anymore.  As for the cookie problems, we can't fix that if you do not provide specific details about it.  I tested the updated cookie logic that I checked in and it has been working for me so far.

Comment: No, I hadn't post those patches to the Indy team because I didn't find a place where it could be done. I downloading snapshots from indy.fulgan.com for last years and just don't know how to send patches quick and in right place. If you give me an url or direct e-mail I'll send all my findings with joy because my software intensively uses TidHTTP, TidCookieManager and so on.

Comment: @Remy: It would be very nice if you explain the way to send patches in the documentation, indy official page, readme.txt, etc.

Comment: You can email patches/updates to myself or any other Indy team member directly, or send them to the Indy-Dev-Public mailing list at http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Indy-Dev-Public/, the Indy NNTP newsgroups at news://news.atozed.com, the Indy HTTP forums at http://forums2.atozed.com, or the Embarcadero Internet forums at http://forums.embarcadero.com or news://forums.embarcadero.com.