# Indy 9 + Delphi 2007 latest SSL Libraries available?

Tags: delphi, ssl, delphi-2007, indy-9

When using Delphi 2007 along with Indy 9, what are the latest OpenSSL libraries that can be loaded and where are they available?

Comment: I guess [`this thread`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=59924) should help.

Comment: Just a sidenote, wouldn't be better for you to [`upgrade Indy to the latest version`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3610176/960757) ?

Comment: Yes, it would be 'better' to upgrade.  It would also be 'better' for everyone to also upgrade to Delphi XE2 Update 4 on everything...

Comment: Yeah, but unlike the upgrade from Delphi 2007 to XE2, the upgrade of Indy is free :-)

Comment: Definitely not free.  Free to download, but not free to rewrite and redeploy what uses it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the following two DLLs:

- libeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

You can download the source from the open-source organization [OpenSSL.org](http://www.openssl.org/source/), but then you have to compile the DLLs yourself.  Indy maintains a site of compiled binaries for each version of Indy and OpenSSL (see [indy.fulgan.com/SSL](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and [indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/) -- thanks to TLama for the links).

Older versions of Indy are not compatible with the OpenSSL libraries (see [Indy "Could not load SSL Library" with Delphi 2007/Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952676/indy-could-not-load-ssl-library-with-delphi-2007-apache)).  TLama added a comment to your question to look at an Embarcadero discussion about this.  In that discussion, Remy said "try the old 0.9.6 DLLs at http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/".  That's probably the version that you will need to use.

Comment: Or visit one of the official OpenSSL Indy library sites, either [`indy.fulgan.com/SSL`](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) for current versions or [`indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive`](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/) for older versions of compiled binaries. However the question sounds more like *what is the most recent version that can be used with Indy 9 shipped with Delphi 2007*.

Comment: Thanks for the links @TLama.  I'll start using that from now on!  As for what version is compatible..., I have never had backwards compatibility issues.  I have always used the latest DLLs without problems.  The only time I did have issues was when I accidentally used different versions of the two DLLs.

Comment: I've also had no problems using the most recent versions with Delphi 2007 (about 3 years ago), but can't verify it now since I don't have Delphi 2007 at this time. About the links, feel free to add it to your answer...

Comment: Are you using these with Indy 9 and not Indy 10?  From what I recall, Indy 9 required a special build.

Comment: I haven't had issues with the Indy version, but I started using Indy in Delphi 2009...  You may be right about the special build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952676/indy-could-not-load-ssl-library-with-delphi-2007-apache

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me! I am working in Delphi 5 with Indy 9 and struggled to find the right DLLs, I downloaded http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/indy_OpenSSL096m.zip and put both DLLs in my program dir and c:\Windows\System32. Thank you James L and Remy "Gambit" Lebeau, you awesome X-man.